# VB.NET: dealing with multiple dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have this confusion in my mind whenever I have to deal with many dropdownlist (ddl). My question is actually is there any best practice or in-built functions or some work around to deal with such situation. I have given below a scenario as a test case. Lets say I have 4 ddl which are dependent upon the selection of the previous ones.

```
ddlContinent   ddlCountry   ddlCity   ddlCurrency
NorthAmerica   USA          Mumbai    Indian Rupee
Europe         Canada       Colombo   Sri Lanka Rupee
Asia           England      Paris     USD
[All]          India        London    Candian Dollar
               France       Chicago   GBP
               Sri Lanka    Toronto
               [All]        New Delhi
                            [All]
```

`Case1: If someone selects ddlContinent [All] and ddlCountry India; the ddlCity should be Mumbai and New Delhi
Case2: If ddlContinent is Asia and ddlCountry is [All] then ddlCity should be Mumbai, New Delhi and Colombo`

And so on..

The nightmare is that we need to code all the possible if-then conditions for the whole set of possibilities.

Above all, when the actual final output has to be displayed in a Table Object based on the above ddl selections, there again we have to code all the possible if-then conditions.

Is there a short-cut.

Note: The above is a ASP.NET Web Application

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google this: asp.net cascading dropdownlist

Comment: CascadingDropDown is cool, but my requirement is that I have multiple ParentControl. To be specific I have 6 ddl in which 5 are interdependent and above all I have to give the users [All] option. Is there any industry best practice. Come on! usually we see in job websites there are so many ddl and each has [All] option also. How do they populate each ddl based on other ddl's selection. Any expert in this field please..

Answer (score 0):

well i resolved it using one custom class maybe exists better approach but here we go

**Rules**

```
 each ddl have one level
 top level affect to lower ddl
```

**Tools**

```
 one stored procedure
```

Sketch

```
public class DdlLevel
{
  private DropDownList _ddl;
  private IRepository _repository;      
  private int _level;
  private string _displayField;
  private string _valueField;

  public DdlLevel(DropDownList ddl,int level, IRepository repository, string displayField, string valueField ){
    _ddl = ddl;
    _level = level;
    _repository = repository;
    _displayField = displayField; 
    _valueField = valueField;
  }

  public void Refresh(UserOptions userOptions){
    if userOptions.DdlLevelRaiseRefresh > _level){
    DataTable data = _repository.GetTablaFilter(userOptions)
    _dll.DataSource = data;
    _dll.DataTextField = _displayField;
    _dll.DataValueField = _valueField;
    _dll.DataBind();
    if (_dll.Item.Count > 0) _dll.SelectedIndex = 0; 
   }
  }
}
```

in the page do some how

```
private IList<DdlLevel> _ddlRefresh;

page_load(){
  _dllRefresh = DllLevelInit();
}

IList<DdlLevel> DllLevelInit(){
  IList<DdlLevel> list = new List<DdlLevel>();
  list.add(new DdlLevel(firstdll,9,new yourRepository(...),"fieldtodisplay","fieldtostore");
  list.add(new DdlLevel(seconddll,8,new yourRepository(...),"fieldtodisplay","fieldtostore");
  ...
  return list;
}
```

now on each ddl put the same function(in this case Filter) for SelectedIndexChanged event

```
protected void Filter(Object sender, EventArgs e){
    UserOptions options = GetCurrentValuesOfDll(sender);
    for each DdlLevel ddl in _ddlRefresh
       dld.Refresh(options);
}

private UserOptions GetCurrentValuesOfDll(Object sender){
 UserOptions o = new UserOptions;   
    o.DdlLevelRaiseRefresh = GetLevelOfCurrentDdl(sender)
    o.DdlCompany = null;
    If Not (ddlCompany.SelectedValue = "All" Or ddlCompany.SelectedValue = "") Then
        o.DdlCompany = CType(ddlCompany.SelectedValue, Integer)
    End If
   ...
  return o;
}

private int GetLevelOfCurrentDdl(Object sender){
 int level = 0;
 switch(sender.ID){
   case "ddlCompany";
        return 9;
  ...
 }
 return level;
}
```

the sp is some how

```
create stored procedure DllFilterOnMyPage(useroption1, useroption2...)
as
 set nocount on

 if (dllLevel > 8) select 'All' as DisplayField, -0 as ValueToStore union select * from yourtable 
 if (dllLevel > 7) select 'All' as DisplayField, -0 as ValueToStore union select * from yourtable
 ...
```